# Comparing data of any type without overloading

Tags: oracle, plsql

let's start with an example:

```
    type Collection_t is table of varchar2(3);
    Collection_v Collection_t := Collection_t('qwe', 'asd', 'yxc', 'rtz', 'fgh', 'vbn');
    single_var   varchar2(3)  := 'yxc';

    procedure get_position(Single_Value varchar2, Value_Set Collection_t) is
        i integer := 1;
    begin
        while (i is not null) loop
            if Single_Value = Value_Set(i)
            then
                dbms_output.put_line(i);
            end if;
            i := Value_Set.Next(i);
        end loop;
    end;

begin
    get_position(single_var, Collection_v);
end;
```

now, question is: can I declare this procedure with 'anydata', and check if table (2ed argument) consists of the same type as first argument.

I'd assume declaration of a procedure would look like that:

`procedure get_position(Single_Value anydata, Value_Set anydata) is ...`
later I'd compare types, and honestly I couldn't figure it out, how to solve this problem.

Comment: ...and you've written that code with anydata which shows you <???> error, right? You didn't specify the issue you have

Comment: @astentx the code above is just an example, a framework to picture what I want to achieve. I have a problem with using 'anydata'. I could give all failed attempts, but showing all bits and pieces is pointless - it won't add anything to this post, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my limited understanding, you still have to encode/decode `anydata` into basic (or user-defined) PL/SQL types to do anything meaningful like comparing values, so you might not gain the benefits of dynamic languages like Python.

Here is an example, passing `anydata` as a parameter. You'll need to update `anydata_to_varchar` to handle data types you need.

Personally, overloading seems like a more straightforward approach, unless there is a better way to work with `anydata` values.

> ```
> declare
>     type tab_anydata is table of anydata;
>     
>     -- test as varchar2
>     /*
>     lookup_array tab_anydata := tab_anydata(
>         anydata.convertVarchar2('blah'), 
>         anydata.convertVarchar2('meh'), 
>         anydata.convertVarchar2('foo'), 
>         anydata.convertVarchar2('bar')
>     );
>     lookup_value anydata := anydata.convertVarchar2('foo');
>     */
>
>     -- test as date
>     lookup_array tab_anydata := tab_anydata(
>         anydata.convertDate(trunc(sysdate - 2)), 
>         anydata.convertDate(trunc(sysdate - 0)), 
>         anydata.convertDate(trunc(sysdate + 1)), 
>         anydata.convertDate(trunc(sysdate + 2)) 
>     );
>     lookup_value anydata := anydata.convertDate(trunc(sysdate));
>
>     
>     function anydata_to_varchar(p_what anydata)
>     return varchar2
>     is
>         value_type varchar2(30) := anydata.GetTypeName(p_what);
>         result varchar2(32767);
>     begin
>         select 
>         case value_type
>         when 'SYS.VARCHAR2' then anydata.AccessVarchar2(p_what)
>         when 'SYS.DATE' then to_char(anydata.AccessDate(p_what), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
>         when 'SYS.NUMBER' then to_char(anydata.AccessNumber(p_what))
>         else null
>         end into result
>         from dual;
>         
>         return result;
>     end;
>     
>     function get_position(p_what anydata, p_where tab_anydata)
>     return number
>     is
>         pos number := -1;
>         what_value varchar2(30) := anydata_to_varchar(p_what);
>         curr_value varchar2(30);     
>     begin        
>         for i in 1..p_where.count
>         loop
>             curr_value := anydata_to_varchar(p_where(i));
>             if what_value = curr_value then
>                 pos := i;
>                 exit;
>             end if;            
>         end loop;
>         return pos;
>     end;
>
> begin
>     dbms_output.put_line('lookup type   : '||anydata.GetTypeName(lookup_value));
>     dbms_output.put_line('lookup value  : '||anydata_to_varchar(lookup_value));
>     dbms_output.put_line('found position: '||get_position(lookup_value, lookup_array));
> end;
> /
> ```

```
dbms_output:
lookup type   : SYS.DATE
lookup value  : 2022-07-20
found position: 2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7536bcf2ad9c0627618b076d2b967c97)*

Comment: Thanks! I was digging into the subject, realizing there's no such a thing like generics in PL/SQL. I was hoping I could pass any variable and structure/table. Then I could iterate that table and compare to a given variable. 
For that - underlying types must be the same.